# RapidMiner : Where/how is the Store (Model) operator connected in this process flow

Tags: process, rapidminer

I have created a process flow within RapidMiner that utilizes some loops. I'm not exactly sure where my Store Model operator should be connected to, in order to save the model parameters derived through this process to be in a new process.

The attached example has my data replaced with some sample data, however the rest of the process is what I have for my actual data set.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<process version="5.3.012">
  <context>
    <input/>
    <output/>
    <macros/>
  </context>
  <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="5.3.012" expanded="true" name="Process">
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="retrieve" compatibility="5.3.012" expanded="true" height="60" name="Retrieve Sonar" width="90" x="45" y="30">
        <parameter key="repository_entry" value="//Samples/data/Sonar"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="numerical_to_binominal" compatibility="5.3.012" expanded="true" height="76" name="Numerical to Binominal" width="90" x="179" y="30">
        <parameter key="attribute_filter_type" value="single"/>
        <parameter key="attribute" value="20_OV_COVER"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="set_role" compatibility="5.3.012" expanded="true" height="76" name="Set Role" width="90" x="45" y="120">
        <parameter key="attribute_name" value="class"/>
        <parameter key="target_role" value="label"/>
        <list key="set_additional_roles"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="normalize" compatibility="5.3.012" expanded="true" height="94" name="Normalize" width="90" x="179" y="120"/>
      <operator activated="true" class="nominal_to_numerical" compatibility="5.3.012" expanded="true" height="94" name="Nominal to Numerical (2)" width="90" x="45" y="210">
        <list key="comparison_groups"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="replace_missing_values" compatibility="5.3.012" expanded="true" height="94" name="Replace Missing Values" width="90" x="179" y="210">
        <list key="columns"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="independent_component_analysis" compatibility="5.3.012" expanded="true" height="94" name="ICA" width="90" x="313" y="210">
        <parameter key="number_of_components" value="700"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="optimize_selection_forward" compatibility="5.3.012" expanded="true" height="94" name="Forward Selection" width="90" x="514" y="75">
        <parameter key="maximal_number_of_attributes" value="100"/>
        <parameter key="speculative_rounds" value="10"/>
        <process expanded="true">
          <operator activated="true" class="x_validation" compatibility="5.3.012" expanded="true" height="112" name="Validation" width="90" x="112" y="30">
            <parameter key="number_of_validations" value="5"/>
            <process expanded="true">
              <operator activated="true" class="naive_bayes" compatibility="5.3.012" expanded="true" height="76" name="Naive Bayes" width="90" x="112" y="30"/>
              <connect from_port="training" to_op="Naive Bayes" to_port="training set"/>
              <connect from_op="Naive Bayes" from_port="model" to_port="model"/>
              <portSpacing port="source_training" spacing="0"/>
              <portSpacing port="sink_model" spacing="0"/>
              <portSpacing port="sink_through 1" spacing="0"/>
            </process>
            <process expanded="true">
              <operator activated="true" class="apply_model" compatibility="5.3.012" expanded="true" height="76" name="Apply Model" width="90" x="45" y="30">
                <list key="application_parameters"/>
              </operator>
              <operator activated="true" class="performance" compatibility="5.3.012" expanded="true" height="76" name="Performance" width="90" x="276" y="30"/>
              <connect from_port="model" to_op="Apply Model" to_port="model"/>
              <connect from_port="test set" to_op="Apply Model" to_port="unlabelled data"/>
              <connect from_op="Apply Model" from_port="labelled data" to_op="Performance" to_port="labelled data"/>
              <connect from_op="Performance" from_port="performance" to_port="averagable 1"/>
              <portSpacing port="source_model" spacing="0"/>
              <portSpacing port="source_test set" spacing="0"/>
              <portSpacing port="source_through 1" spacing="0"/>
              <portSpacing port="sink_averagable 1" spacing="0"/>
              <portSpacing port="sink_averagable 2" spacing="0"/>
            </process>
          </operator>
          <connect from_port="example set" to_op="Validation" to_port="training"/>
          <connect from_op="Validation" from_port="averagable 1" to_port="performance"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_example set" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_performance" spacing="0"/>
        </process>
      </operator>
      <connect from_op="Retrieve Sonar" from_port="output" to_op="Numerical to Binominal" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Numerical to Binominal" from_port="example set output" to_op="Set Role" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Set Role" from_port="example set output" to_op="Normalize" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Normalize" from_port="example set output" to_op="Nominal to Numerical (2)" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Nominal to Numerical (2)" from_port="example set output" to_op="Replace Missing Values" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Replace Missing Values" from_port="example set output" to_op="ICA" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="ICA" from_port="example set output" to_op="Forward Selection" to_port="example set"/>
      <connect from_op="ICA" from_port="original" to_port="result 1"/>
      <connect from_op="ICA" from_port="preprocessing model" to_port="result 2"/>
      <connect from_op="Forward Selection" from_port="example set" to_port="result 3"/>
      <connect from_op="Forward Selection" from_port="attribute weights" to_port="result 4"/>
      <connect from_op="Forward Selection" from_port="performance" to_port="result 5"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="18"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 3" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 4" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 5" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 6" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
</process>
```

Comment: It would make a lot more sense if you asked this in the RapidMiner community forums, as this essentially is an application use question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

The forward selection operator outputs a set of weights and these can be used to select the attributes that the operator found to give the best performance. The first thing to do therefore is to use these weights with the Select by Weight operator to give the example set that was used to build the model.

From there you could simply rebuild the model with this example set outside the Forward Selection operator. If you additionally wanted to get an estimate of the performance on unseen data you could use a Validation block on all the data but if not then simply using the model operator would create the model you need.

When I tried it, the estimated performance I got was different to the one produced by the Forward Selection operator because the partitioning in the validation block is different owing to different random number seeds. It is also the case that the Validation block inside the Forward Selection is giving an average performance for 10 models built on 10 partitions of data. These 10 models could all be different so there is no one true model that can be saved.

Hope that helps.

regards

Andrew

Comment: I noticed this is cross posted from statsexchange. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68220/where-how-is-the-store-model-operator-connected-in-this-process-flow-in-rapidm   Perhaps the original poster would be so kind as to perform some housekeeping.